# mongodb how to update a element of the array in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I want to update mobile in guardians,
The document is in the following form

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575e4d850d61a206084ff035"),
    "students" : [
            {
                    "_id": "58454c8fd01c35cb06ac1d7c",
                    "guardians": [
                         {
                             _id: "5710b9dbb6744ac07aee6a6d",
                             contact: {
                                 mobile: "15800000000"
                             }
                         }
                         ...
                     ]
            }
            ...
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the $set operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays

Comment: Updated based on a condition， like this
ClassModel.update(
     {
      'students.guardians._id': userId,
      'status': { $ne: 'deleted' }
     },
     {
      $set: {
       'students.$.guardians.$.contact.mobile': mobile
      }
     },
     { multi: true },
     function(e) {
      next(e);
     }
    );